# Basic php form with method post stopped to work

Tags: php, forms

on a wordpress blog I have several pages with forms that show results (like quizzes) that are not working anymore. I'd like to understand why they stopped to work and fix them. Maybe is something related to php version (they worked for many years, but I think they stopped to work after some updates.
Here an example

The form page:

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
    Question 1
    <input name="key1" value="1" checked="checked" type="radio" />Yes
    <input name="key1" value="2" type="radio" />No
    <input name="key1" value="3" type="radio" />Don't know
    Question 2
    <input name="key2" value="1" checked="checked" type="radio" />Yes
    <input name="key2" value="2" type="radio" />No
    <input name="key2" value="3" type="radio" />Don't know
    <input name="SEND" type="submit" value="Show result" />
    </form>`
```

The result.php page

```
<?php 
    if ($key1==1) {$risposta1=2;}
    else if ($key1==2) {$risposta1=1;} 
    else {$risposta1=0;}
    if ($key2==1) {$risposta2=2;}
    else if ($key2==2) {$risposta2=1;} 
    else {$risposta2=0;}
    $result = $risposta1 + $risposta2;
    ?>
    <? print $result ?>
```

I have PHP Version 5.3.29

Comment: The are no $_POST variables in this code. Also, what updates were done? If you were using register globals and then updated PHP then you need to fix your code as that is no longer available.

Comment: I don't see any code that will break even if using PHP 7. Might also be helpful if you show the error. Also check if you enabled short opening tags `<? `, or just use `<?php` instead.

Comment: You might want to at least tell us what "doesn't work" means.  How *specifically* does this fail?

Comment: Ok, stopped to works I mean that in result page nothing is calculated, it returns zero even key1 and key2 are set to 1 or 2
Thanks again for useful comments

Answer (score 2):

It appears your code relied on [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) being enabled, a dangerous feature which was deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 and removed in 5.4.0. Also it appears that short PHP tags (`<?`) are used, which are also not recommended.

You have to change your code like this:

```
<?php 

$key1 = $_POST['key1'];
$key2 = $_POST['key2'];

if ($key1==1) {$risposta1=2;}
else if ($key1==2) {$risposta1=1;} 
else {$risposta1=0;}
if ($key2==1) {$risposta2=2;}
else if ($key2==2) {$risposta2=1;} 
else {$risposta2=0;}
$result = $risposta1 + $risposta2;

echo $result;
```

The most important change here is that `$key1` and `$key2` are read out of the `$_POST` superglobal array which contains the values sent using HTTP POST. Previously PHP auto-set these variables for you, which (while adding a bit of convenience) allowed clients to inject arbitrary variables into your code through HTTP which is a very dangerous thing to do; that's why this feature was removed.